# Future plans to consider for asp.net mvc 5.2 web application, with releasing asp.net mvc6 (vnext)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need to get any ideas of how i should be managing our previous asp.net MVC 5.2 web application.. now i am using asp.net mvc-5.2 with entity framework 6.0. and i want to start phase-2 for some of these projects. so should i consider upgrading my mvc 5.2 to be using mvc6 (vnext) first ? and will there be any migration plans ?
second question , when is it expected for vnext to be released? or it is has been officially released ?

third question, will i be able to create a vnext project inside VS 2012 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would simply recommend following the standard best practice of n-tier architecture and keeping logic related to things like querying a database in class libraries. MVC 6 is *drastically* different from previous versions, so there's no easy migration. You'll basically need to start a brand new project and move over relevant code where you can and spend a good bit of time converting code. For example, child actions are gone and have been replaced with view components. You'll need to go through any child actions you're using currently and create view components out of them. As I said, making sure your current MVC project is as thin as possible (by factoring out code into class libraries and such) will go a long way in reducing the amount of code you need to move/change.
2. As far as I'm aware, no release date has been set, but at least in the alpha and beta phases of Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET 5/MVC 6, Windows 10 has been required, so there won't be an official release likely until Windows 10 is public. However, Visual Studio 2015 has reached release cadidate stage, so I'd say it's definitely close, either launching alongside Windows 10 or shortly after.
3. Kind of answered this in point 2, but ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 will require VS2015. As far as I'm aware, there's no plans to add support to lesser versions. A lot of that has to do with Rosyln, the new .NET compiler. Trying to bootstrap previous versions of VS with support for an entirely new compiler/syntax engine would be a monstrous task. However, VS has been on an MSDN subscription model for many versions now and as long as you're a current subscriber you can always download the latest version for free. If you're not an MSDN subscriber, you can still download the community edition of VS 2015 for free. It's missing a lot of the more advanced VS features, but it's still totally sufficient for web development work.

Comment: thanks for your helpful reply,, so if currently my projects are working  well on mvc 5.2 , so is there any reason that i should not contiiuse using asp.net mvc 5.2 in the next couple of years ? what do u think ? if you face similar situation ?

Comment: The benefits of MVC 6 are myriad, but there's no technical reason you can't continue to use MVC 5 for the foreseeable future. I am actually in a similar situation, nearing the launch of an MVC 5 app long in development. I hope to migrate it to MVC 6 at some point in the future, I plan to let the dust settle on MVC 6 first. The shift is dramatic, almost mirroring the introduction of MVC 1.0. I fully expect for the code to bounce around a bit until it matures somewhat.

Comment: so the migration process will be mainly manual process of converting any no longer available components in asp.net mvc6 compared to mvc5. and from my reading mvc6 is mainly merging asp.net mvc5 & asp.net web api together ...I am expecting my entity framework code (model class) to be the same in both , but controller & view will require the main effort to migrate,, but i am also listing the migration from mvc5 to mvc 6 in the future but i will no giveit a highest priority in the current year ...